# How do I get an HP Deskjet F4210 to work?

Tags: drivers, printing, cups

I brought to home my friend's printer (HP Deskjet F4210). I'm using Xubuntu 10.04.
When I use the command

```
lpr scanned.pdf
```

the printer does nothing. `lpq` writes

```
Deskjet-F300-series is not ready
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
1st     xralf 61      scanned.pdf                     1690624 bytes
2nd     xralf 62      (stdin)                         0 bytes
3rd     xralf 63      scanned.pdf                     1690624 bytes
```

I installed the driver according to this [manual](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_f4210_series.html)

It was possible to print a test page after installation.

Could you help me to figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo lpoptions -d HP_Deskjet_F4200_series
```

This command solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the printer status in the cups web control panel (general found at http://localhost:631) and make sure the printer isn't paused. Also make sure the cups daemon is running.

Comment: The printer isn't paused in http://localhost:631. It's status is Idle now.

How can I find out that cups deamon is running? I used the commands cupsd and cupsenable.

lpq still shows
**Deskjet-F300-series is not ready**
which is my own printer that is disconnected. I'd like to print with F4210 printer.